# Installing active SQL server instance on passive node, no network settings field

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm installing an active-active MSSQL server 2008r2 instance.  While trying to install the second active node on the first passive node, I get to the network configuration page and there are no fields.  Normally there are fields to enter IP settings, no?  Am I going crazy?
[image]

Comment: I also tried adding another IP address to the network interface (even though I'm pretty sure I don't need to) and that got me the same result.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you run Cluster Validation, does it point out any networking warnings or errors?